# Last element deletion of link list with only one pointer

Tags: c, linked-list, traversal

If we have one pointer pointing at the last element of link list and we don't have any other pointer pointing to any other node of the link list then is it possible to delete that last node safely?
As per my opinion its not possible.

[image]

Comment: Explain "delete"? If you have no mean to have a pointer to the previous node in order to change its `next` to NULL then no, you can't "delete" it.

Comment: when I say delete it means proper deletion.
One could simply free that pointer but still the previous node will have the address of recently deleted node as it's not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not possible** if you do not have reference to the second last element of the list. You need to make the *pointer* part of the second last element *null*. So as per my knowledge, if you only have a reference to the last element, then deleting it is not possible.

An exceptional case will be when there is only one element in the list which is the first as well as the last element. In such a case, freeing that element will not cause any harm.

When you have a linked-list, you need to have a reference to the first element using which you traverse the entire list. But when you say you do not have any reference to the list except the last element, this is a very unusual case.